# How to count the number of stackdriver metrics using by GCP resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have used two external metrics (prometheus) as well as used three log based metrics for monitoring the GKE containers , POD  & Cloud SQL .

Through stackdriver metric i could able to get the volume of metric data ingested specifically for above metrics (external & Log-based) but couldn't able to find the exact count of metrics leveraged .

Metric volume data's are generating from multiple metrics , Even though I have specifically used only 5 metrics . Any reason for that ?

Also if metrics are being used by only few resources out of all the resources then how GCP will calculate the price ? Bcoz the calculation is based on number of resources * No. of Metrics * data point

Thanks,
Deena

Comment: By "count of metrics leveraged" do you mean the number of metrics being monitored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [list of metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics) available to each service. If you require you can count up the ones applicable to you.

Regarding Monitoring pricing the following metrics are non-chargeable (free):

- Google Cloud metrics
- Anthos metrics
- Istio metrics
- Knative metrics
- Google Kubernetes Engine metrics
- agent.googleapis.com/agent/ metrics

However, the External metrics and Logs-based metrics are chargeable and priced by ingested volume as shown below. [Pricing documentation and examples](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#monitoring-costs).

- $0.2580/MiB: 150–100,000 MiB
- $0.1510/MiB: 100,000–250,000 MiB
- $0.0610/MiB: > 250,000 MiB